nix-build for Pluto takes hours -- stills haven't finished
I have installed Nix 2.20.5 in my ubuntu 22.04.4, following Readme I ran nix-build in Pluto directory.
It's taking several hours(>4) in building packages,not sure hong long it will need to finish the whole building process.
Is there any better way to run the build to shorten the time?
